# Strange Magento 2.4.6-p2 PageBuilder problem while installing "Missing required argument $characterSet of Gt\Dom\Document"

Tags: magento2.4.6, page-builder, dom

Can somebody help?
I have installed magento 2.4.6-p2 and wanted to install Pagebuilder.
So I downloaded "magento2-page-builder-develop", but i get an error while compiling:

Unable to apply data patch Magento\PageBuilder\Setup\Patch\Data\UpgradePageBuilderStripStyles for module Magento_PageBuilder. Original exception message: Missing required argument $characterSet of Gt\Dom\Document.

After that when I did setup:di:compile
I get these errors:

Compilation was started.
Area configuration aggregation... 5/9 [===============>------------]  55% 27 secs 276.0 MiB
In ClassReader.php line 57:

Impossible to process constructor argument Parameter #1 [  Gt\Dom\TokenList $tokenList ] of Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Dom\TokenList class

In GetParameterClassTrait.php line 34:

Class "Gt\Dom\TokenList" does not exist

I dont know what do?
Help???

Comment: Page builder in-bult in Magetno2.4.6-p2. No need to installation.